# Не понимаю как присвоить value через цикл в инпуты

Tags: javascript

```
Помогите решить простым js для новичка что бы все было понятно и просто без наворотов

<p><b>Task 13</b></p>
                    <p>Кнопка b-13 запускает функцию t13. Функция должна:
                        получить все input.i-13
                        перебрать их с помощью цикла. Обращение к элементу выглядит так elem[i]
                        применить к каждому elem[i].value, причем к value первого должно равняться 1, второго - 2, третьего -
                        3...
                    </p>
                    <div class="form-control">
                        <label>Input i-13</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter some info" class="i-13">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-control">
                        <label>Input i-13</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter some info" class="i-13">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-control">
                        <label>Input i-13</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter some info" class="i-13">
                    </div>
        
       let input_13 = document.querySelectorAll('.i-13');
    
    function t13() {
            for(let i = 0; i < input_13.length; i++){
                input_13[i].value = i;   
                // input_13[i[0]].value = 1;
                // input_13[i[1]].value = 2;
                // input_13[i[2]].value = 3;
            } 
        }
    
    document.querySelector('.b-13').onclick = t13;
```

Comment: так у вас всё сделано кроме +1

Comment: в html в input не отображается value при нажатие кнопки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let input_13 = document.querySelectorAll('.i-13');
    
function t13() {
    for (let i = 0; i < input_13.length; i++){
        input_13[i].value = i + 1;   
    } 
    
    //for (let i = 1; i <= input_13.length; i++){
    //    input_13[i - 1].value = i;   
    //} 
}

document.querySelector('.b-13').onclick = t13;
```

```html
<div class="form-control">
    <label>Input i-13</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter some info" class="i-13">
</div>
<div class="form-control">
    <label>Input i-13</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter some info" class="i-13">
</div>
<div class="form-control">
    <label>Input i-13</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter some info" class="i-13">
</div>
<button class="b-13">b-13</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector('.button').onclick = function f() {
    let a = document.querySelectorAll('.input');
    for ( let i = 0;i<a.length;i++){
       a[i].value=+i+1; 
    }
}//Инпуты будут начинаться с цифры 1.
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]